# objects not working in SDL (C++)

Tags: c++, class, object, sdl, undefined

I am working on a simple game in C++, with SDL as my API. I put my image bliting functions  in a class on a separate document so that it would less messy on my main file. However, when I try to call the functions using the object for the class, my IDE says that I am making an undefined reference to the functions. Here is the main file:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"
#include "imageBlitingFunctions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int screenW = 640;
int screenH = 480;
int screenBPP = 32;

SDL_Surface* window = SDL_SetVideoMode(screenW, screenH, screenBPP, SDL_SWSURFACE);

imageBlitingFunctions IBFobject;

SDL_Surface* background1;
SDL_Surface* player1;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    TTF_Init();

    background1 = IBFobject.loadIMG("background.png");
    player1 = IBFobject.loadIMG("swordtest.png");

    IBFobject.blitIMG(0, 0, window, background1, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    IBFobject.blitIMG(0, 0, window, player1, 100, 0, 100, 300);

    SDL_FreeSurface(background1);
    SDL_FreeSurface(player1);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the header for the class:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef IMAGEBLITINGFUNCTIONS_H
#define IMAGEBLITINGFUNCTIONS_H


class imageBlitingFunctions
{
    public:
        SDL_Surface *loadIMG(std::string filename);

        void blitIMG(int pX, int pY, SDL_Surface *window, SDL_Surface *image, int cpX, int cpY, int cpH, int cpW);

        SDL_Surface *loadText(int red, int blue, int green, std::string fontname, int fontSize, std::string text);
};

#endif // IMAGEBLITINGFUNCTIONS_H
```

And here is the class:

```
#include "imageBlitingFunctions.h"
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

SDL_Surface* imageBlitingFunctions::loadIMG(std::string filename)
{
    SDL_Surface *img = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());

    SDL_Surface *imgOPT = SDL_DisplayFormat(img);

    SDL_FreeSurface(img);

    return imgOPT;
}

void imageBlitingFunctions::blitIMG(int pX, int pY, SDL_Surface *window, SDL_Surface *image, int cpX, int cpY, int cpH, int cpW)
{
    SDL_Rect positionIMG;
    positionIMG.x = pX;
    positionIMG.y = pY;

    SDL_Rect clipP;
    clipP.x = cpX;
    clipP.y = cpY;
    clipP.h = cpH;
    clipP.w = cpW;

    SDL_BlitSurface(image, &clipP, window, &positionIMG);

    SDL_Flip(window);
}

SDL_Surface* imageBlitingFunctions::loadText(int red, int blue, int green, std::string fontname, int fontSize, std::string text)
{
    int color1 = red;
    int color2 = blue;
    int color3 = green;

    SDL_Color textColor = {color1, color2, color3};

    TTF_Font *font1 = TTF_OpenFont(fontname.c_str(), fontSize);

    SDL_Surface *message1 = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font1, text.c_str(), textColor);

    return message1;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An undefined reference to a function means that the linker can't find the function definition. The definition of the function is what you've put in the code "And here is the class:" (maybe you call it imageBlitingFunctions.cpp or something similar?) so the problem is that you're IDE can't find this file.

To solve this problem you need to fix the project configuration.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Turned out I hadn't added the class and header file to my sources. But now I have a new problem, the program launches fine, but the window immediately closes after opening, and the console says that "process returned 3." I ran the debugger and it says this is a segmentation fault?